# Visiting all nodes in a DAG using a greedy algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm trying to visit all the nodes within a directed acyclic graph using a greedy algorithm. I was thinking that something like depth first search would work but I'm not sure how this would work with a DAG as I cannot trace myself back through the graph.

Thanks.

Comment: If you just want to visit all the nodes why do you need to 'trace yourself back'?

Comment: Because If I go down the graph without backtracking, it doesn't necessarily mean that I will visit every node.

Comment: If it's acyclic and directed, when you run out of nodes to inspect, i.e. you get to the end of all paths, where can a node exist without being visited?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use either depth-first search (DFS) or breadth-first search (BFS), check any good texbook, for instance, "Introduction to Algorithms" by Thomas H. Cormen.

You do not need to use edges to "trace yourself back", use either a stack (or recursion) or a queue.

Comment: Using the call stack is the most straightforward implementation :-)

Comment: If you would check "Introduction to Algorithms" by Thomas H. Cormen, don't be afraid at the beginning - you don't need to read and understand all content in it - it is good book for long algorithmics learning.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes, but you can easily overflow it. You should use the call stack with care:)

Comment: @DixonD admittably, recursion is problematic over 100k-node graps :-)

Comment: From my knowledge, DFS and BFS are not considered greedy algorithms tho.

Comment: @YamatoC DFS is as greedy as a graph traversal algorithm can get, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

```
void dfs(node V) {
    mark V as visited;
    for each edge E, so that E.source = V, do {
        if(E.destination is not marked as visited) {
            dfs(E.destination);
        }
    }
}
```

That's it. What DFS(recursion) does, is to return to its caller instance when current instance is finished. As it uses stack for keeping all active instances, you don't have to go back yourself, it automatically rolls back into previous node when function is finished execution on current node.

Comment: Your algorithm is usually what is needed to find one connected component in a undirected graph. For a DAG, this must be performed several times by scanning the list of nodes and running dfs on each unmarked node, until there isn't  any such node.

Comment: Yes, if the DAG is not connected, this should be called for each component, but that is how everything works, it doesn't change main idea.